# Handlers and Databases GoLang

Tags: database, go

So I have a local database that uses mongoDB, and I want to print values from that DB to the localhost http server but for some reason I can't figure out how to get the values from it. This is what I've tried for my handler so far:

```
func outputHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c := session.DB("foo").C("WOO")
    countTemp := c.Find(nil)


    outputString, err := json.Marshal(countTemp)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    w.Write(outputString) 
}
```

The reason I have it as c.Find(nil) is because I know that the database only has 1 value at any given time, and that is the value I want to retrieve. When the output below is ran, my response on localhost/:8080/foo is {}.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This client is not maintained anymore you might have better luck with https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver

Comment: test to see if it knows your database: `dbs, err := session.DatabaseNames()`, and if you have it test to see if the collection is there: `colls, err := session.DB{"foo").CollectionNames()`

Comment: @RickyA The driver you mentioned is vastly different from mgo. However, there is a community maintained fork of mgo https://github.com/globalsign/mgo

Answer (score 3):

[c.Find](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Find) returns a query.  You need to execute the query to get the data:

```
var countTemp interface{}
if err := c.Find(nil).One(&countTemp); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```